# Terraform-like auto-update db with liquibase/flyway, possible?

Tags: liquibase, flyway

We are still in the early phases of our project and we are building a database with several table.
Both of the listed tools allow us to create some DDL/DML files and to track changes to the db. 
Anyway this can be cumbersome when the structure is still not consolidated.

Suppose I want to add a new column, or even delete a table: in both of the programs I have to create a new script with ALTER TABLE/etc. command and document the change.

In terraform you just write your desired infrastructure and when you change the file by removing a node the tool only updates what is already there.

Would it be possible to just list the tables in a file and when I, for example, delete a table definition the tool just updates the existing schema?
Ditto if someone changes the schema by using another tool.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't mind losing data (sounds like this could be OK from your question), Flyway has the `cleanOnValidationError` flag.

This way you can work with one (or more) SQL files and as soon you run migrate and a previously run file has changed, Flyway will report a validation error which in turn will wipe the schema clean before having Flyway immediately set it all up again according to the latest definitions.

They is incredibly useful for rapid iterations in development.